# Domain without www redirect to external service

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, virtualhost

I'm wondering what I'm missing: I've got a vhost working as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.mydomain.co.uk
   ServerAlias mydomain.co.uk
   Redirect permanent / https://www.mydomain.co.uk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/myapp"
    ServerName www.mydomain.co.uk
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile ..
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ..
    SSLCertificateChainFile ..
    ServerAdmin myemail.com
    PassengerDefaultUser www-data
        <Directory "/var/www/myapp">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And when I try `www.mydomain.co.uk` it does redirect to `https://www.mydomain.co.uk` as expected.

However when I try `mydomain.co.uk` I get redirected to a service provider (like a parking domain company).

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your server name to

> mydomain.uk.co

And your server alias to

> *.mydomain.uk.co

Should fix your issue.

Covers you in the event you do or do not type in the www. (Or anything else)...

Comment: Very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CNAME record as following.

*.mydomain.co.uk

Or indeed A record

*.mydomain.co.uk

Comment: So its not an Apache issue but a CNAME issue?

Comment: I think so yes, as it sounds as if your DNS provider is pushing you back to the default IP set when you buy a domain.

Comment: Log into your DNS control panel and check what the *.mydomain.co.uk is set to.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that

`dig www.mydomain.co.uk`

and 

`dig mydomain.co.uk`

returns you same ip address. If not - it's dns issue
If yes - check `NameVirtualHost` directive in apache.conf

Comment: It seems they both return the same IP... what now?

Comment: now search for NameVirtualHost in apache.conf, it should look like NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443